# Запуск задачи

Tags: c#

При выполнении условия должна запуститься задача c именем Zadacha1,как можно это сделать?

```
public void fooTask(ITaskBase task,Context context)
{ 
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;// текущая дата
    DateTime date = context.DateOfReceipt.AddDays(2);
    if (now > date) {  //task.Subject="Zadacha1";
        // Какой код добавить сюда?
    }
}
```

Comment: >prosrochka
>DataPostupleniyaZayavki
>srok
>Zadacha1

сделайте меня развидеть это

Comment: Простите, а что такое `ITaskBase`?